# Is the del statement always 100% the same as calling __delitem__?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a= something iterable object in python
del a[1]
```

Is `del a[1]` always the same as `a.__delitem__(1)`?

Is the Python `del` statement defined as a call to the `__delitem__` method?

Comment: Useful link: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement

Comment: thank for reply Rob. But i already read that and still confused.

Comment: And from the other end: [docs for `object.__delitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__delitem__).  Basically, yes, but only when using `del obj[key]`.  Note that `del obj` *does not* call [`obj.__del__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) directly

Comment: Well, the `del` statement can also be used on attributes, globals, and locals, not just items. `del spam.eggs` is a call to `spam.__delattr__('eggs')`, and what `del spam` compiles to depends on whether it's a local, a nonlocal, or a global/builtin/unknown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The `del` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement) works on any [target list](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-target_list), which includes subscriptions (`del spam[1]`) and slicings (`del spam[:3]`), but also attributions (`del spam.eggs`) and identifiers (`del spam`). And it does different things in each case.

The documentation for the statement maybe doesn't do a great job explaining how each of these cases work, but the [Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__delitem__) chapter fills in some of the gaps.

---

[`__delitem__(self, key)`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__delitem__):

> Called to implement deletion of `self[key]`.

This includes slicings, of course; if you `del spam[:3]`, it will call `spam.__delitem__(slice(None, 3))`.

---

[`__delattr__(self, name)`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__delattr__):

> Like `__setattr__()` but for attribute deletion instead of assignment. This should only be implemented if `del obj.name` is meaningful for the object.

---

In theory, a [`__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) on the class or metaclass could reroute these calls. But since both of these calls are done via [special method lookup](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-lookup), Python is allowed to look the methods up directly, and, at least in CPython 3.7 and 2.7, it does. So, `__delitem__` or `__delattr__` will always be called.

---

For identifiers, what happens depends on whether the compiler identifies the variable as a local, nonlocal, or global. This uses the same rules as any other variable reference.<sup>1</sup>

For globals, this effectively means `del globals()['spam']`. For locals, it's sort of like `del locals()['spam']`, except that it actually affects the local environment. For nonlocals, it essentially calls a `delete_contents()` function on the closure cell.

---

It may help to use the [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) module to see how CPython compiles the different forms of the `del` statement, and then look up what each of the bytecodes does.<sup>2</sup> Of course that's specific to CPython, but it demonstrates what any Python implementation needs to do, however it chooses to do it.

---

<sub>1. But notice that deletion counts as a binding operation, just like assignment does. So, unless `spam` is declared `global` or `nonlocal` (or the code is at the top level), `del spam` is going to make `spam` local.</sub>

<sub>2. Then again, if you don't know anything about bytecode, fast locals, etc., it probably won't help very much…</sub>